# Why wont my form validation work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Im creating a form for a project and I have to set a validation rule so that if nothing is entered for the name then an alert will appear telling the user that a "Name must be filled out" I know this is probably a silly rookie mistake but I'm not quite sure why Its not working as I'm new to javascript.

I haven't included the CSS as its unnecessary. I'm also not posting the information to anything yet.

```js
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
  </script>
 </head>
```

```html
 <body>
 <div class="form_settings">
          <form name="MyForm"  onSubmit="return validateForm()" 
 method="post">
            <p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" 
  name="fname" value="" /></p>
            <p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text" 
  name="your_email" value="" /></p>
            <p><span>Re type Email Address</span><input class="contact" 
 type="text" name="your_email" value="" /></p>
            <p><span>Message</span><textarea class="contact textarea" 
 rows="8" cols="50" name="your_enquiry"></textarea></p>
            <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span><input 
class="submit" type="submit" name="contact_submitted" value="Submit" /></p>
          </form>

 </body>
```

Comment: Syntax is completely wrong. Checkout your browser's console.

Comment: You have two syntax errors with missing closing braces. Also, names are case sensitive so `document.forms["MyForm"]...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contact")[0].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
    }

    return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="MyForm" onsubmit="validateForm();">
        <p><span>Name</span>
            <input class="contact" type="text" name="fname" value="" />
        </p>
        <p><span>Name</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="fname" value="" /></p>
        <p><span>Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="" /></p>

        <p><span>Re type Email Address</span><input class="contact" type="text" name="your_email" value="" /></p>

        <p><span>Message</span><textarea class="contact textarea" rows="8" cols="50" name="your_enquiry"></textarea></p>

        <p style="padding-top: 15px"><span>&nbsp;</span>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
```